# Best data structure for "set with class member as key"?

Tags: c++, c++14, std

I have this data structure:

```
class foo {
   class bar key;
   … some_associated_values …
};
```

I now want to build a unordered_set/map/whatever using this. My problem is that C++14 doesn't support using the key by itself to find members of a set, so unordered_set is out. Using a map would require splitting the value class, or to duplicate the key, but both would require some intrusive refactoring of my existing code base.

The ideal data structure for a mapping like this seems to be a `std::pair<const class key&, class value>` (replacing the key inside the value class with a reference would also work) – but how would I initialize that, preferably in a portable way?

Comment: Doesn't help in this case, because unordered_set::find() must be called with a complete "class foo". The full code uses templates; my code doesn't know (nor should it care) how to initialize a "class foo". I can't require it to have an empty initializer.

Comment: _"C++14 doesn't support using the key by itself to find members of a set"_ Doesn't it?

Comment: It is doable with various degrees of compromise between legality and performance. Can you store a `unique_ptr<foo>`? Can you require `foo` to have a virtual `bar& get_key()`?

Comment: Perhaps wrap it in a `class foo_wrapper { bool has_foo; union { class bar key; class foo foo; } u; }`. When inserting, set `has_foo = true` and `u.foo = the_thing_to_insert`. When finding, set `has_foo = false` and `u.key = the_thing_to_find`. Your custom comparator compares only keys. Your custom hash hashes only the key. You will need a custom destructor to manage the union.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit set::find method accepts a member reference. Subclassing it to add another method doesn't work because the internal storage (hash or redblack tree or whatever) is not accessible.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs: Okay

Comment: One possibility is to store foo objects in a list (`std::list<foo>`), and use a separate map to translate key references into list iterators: (`std::unordered_map<const key&, std::list<foo>::iterator>`).

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that C++14 doesn't support using the key by itself to find members of a set

In C++14 you can use a `std::set` but not a `std::unordered_set` (because unordered containers don't support heterogeneous lookup):

```
#include <set>
#include <assert.h>

struct bar { int i; };

bool operator<(const bar& l, const bar& r) { return l.i < r.i; }

struct foo
{
  bar key;
  int val;
};

struct cmp
{
  using is_transparent = void;

  bool operator()(const foo& l, const foo& r) const
  {
    return l.key < r.key;
  }

  bool operator()(const foo& l, const bar& r) const
  {
    return l.key < r;
  }

  bool operator()(const bar& l, const foo& r) const
  {
    return l < r.key;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::set<foo, cmp> s;
  s.insert(foo{{0}, 1});
  s.insert(foo{{2}, 3});

  auto pos = s.find(bar{0});
  assert( pos != s.end() );
  assert( pos->key.i == 0 );
  assert( pos->val == 1 );

  pos = s.find(bar{1});
  assert( pos == s.end() );

  pos = s.find(bar{2});
  assert( pos != s.end() );
  assert( pos->key.i == 2 );
  assert( pos->val == 3 );
}
```

---

(P.S. It is [possible](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/500d52f81843ccdc) to make something using `unordered_map` work, but it's vile, and error-prone.)